# Policy File Conversion

Tags: java, security, policyfiles

How to convert a policy configuration text file in to a Policy object, to be used in the method call *Policy.setPolicy()* ([API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html))?